# How can I show text labels on buttons globally?

Tags: macos, ui, accessibility

How do I display text in addition to icons in toolbar buttons?

For example, I find some of the icons in the Preview app to be quite unintuitive.

[image: Screenshot of Preview]

Is there a way to set this globally across all apps?

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet found a way to set this globally across all apps.

For the Preview app, you can right-click on the toolbar button or <kbd>control</kbd>-click, and then select "Icon and text" to get this result:

[image: Screenshot of Preview with icons that have text labels]

Comment: I believe you are correct. This is an app preference and not something that you can globally set for all apps.